# JWT tokens flow - log out case

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I am creating node.js/express project. Authentication is done based on JWT. Details:

1. When user log in, in response there is access token (validation: 15 minutes) and refresh token (validation: 24 hours). In payload of each token there are user's most neccessary data and unique identifier which is used to make these token kind of pairs. These tokens are "bond". On logout this identifier is put on blacklist - for more read below.
2. In each request I check access token: a) if token is real token (not faked one), b) if it is expired or c) token contains in its payload an unique identifier which was put on the blacklist. In case access token expired check out no 3 below.
3. When access token expired, there sie /refreshToken endpoint where user can refresh both access token and refresh tokens. In case unique identifier is in the blacklist token will not be refreshed and user should re-authenticate.
4. And finally, there is /logout endpoint where user pass access token in request. And again, if unique identifier is in blacklist there is error in response. However if access token is valid, unique identifier is put on the blacklist and user is logged out.

What I need to mention here is I do not store refresh tokens in database as in many other solutions. All is based on unique identifier.

Basically, my goal was to be sure that when user logged out (access token in request), no one will use refresh token to regain access token. In this solution both tokens should be useless.

What do you think of this flow. What do you think of unique identifier which pairs both access and refresh token?
Would you improve that in any way?